# Как найти аналог команды в ассемблере?

Tags: ассемблер

Нужно найти аналог этой команде

выглядит в hex виде это так:    B9SSSSSSSS3680310E4181F9LLLLLLLL75F3E9JJJJJJJJ

```
00401945 >  B9 XXXXXXXX     MOV ECX,XXXXXXXX
 0040194B    36:8031 0E      XOR BYTE PTR SS:[ECX],0E
 0040194F    41              INC ECX
 00401950    81F9 XXXXXXXX   CMP ECX,XXXXXXXX
 00401956  ^ 75 F3           JNZ SHORT 0040194B
 00401958  ^ E9 XXXXXXXX     JMP XXXXXXXX
```

Comment: Это цикл какой-то. Какой аналог-то нужен?

Comment: прелагай все какие есть

Answer (score 5):

```
BYTE x[...];
BYTE * ecx;
ecx = x; // или ecx = &x[0] что то же самое // mov ecx, XXXXXXXX
do {
(*ecx) ^= 0x0E; // XOR BYTE PTR SS:[ECX],0E
ecx++; // inc ecx
} while(ecx!=XXXXXXX); // CMP ECX,XXXXXXXX, jnz
```

По сути, просто проход по массиву (или строке символов) и применение к каждому элементу XOR 0x0E.

Comment: вот это и было нужно спс

Answer (score 1):

loop ?

Answer (score 0):

Делаете так.

1. По шагам выполняете команды.
2. Составляете блок-схему.
3. Ищете по описанию команд микропроцессора аналог.

Особо не вглядывался, но, наверняка, догадка [@Тортег](/users/5431/%D1%82%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B3) верна, это самый близкий аналого - команда loop с счетчиком в ECX.